# How efficient is databinding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, performance, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have DPs a and b to which c is bound via i converter (note that a and b might be bound to another DP via a converter). I modify a and b or some of the DPs that they are bound to and then use c in a calculation. I do this in a for loop, and it is taking a really long time, the conditions is `i=0; i<100000; i++)`. So I am wondering how efficient is data binding? And should it be used in scenarios like this?
Here is some sample code:

```
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            //... code to pick m based on some random numbers
            hazards[m].Reactant1.Count -= 1;
            hazards[m].Reactant2.Count -= 1;
            hazards[m].Product.Count += 2;
            display.Text = hazards[m].Value.ToString();
        }
```

hazards.Value is bound to the count of the reactants via a converter, the count of the reactants is bound to a textbox text property. m is picked based on the hazard value and some random numbers.

Comment: Sounds like you should separate the view from the model. Look into MVVM.

Comment: @AvadaKedavra I know what MVVM is, but I am not sure how to relate your answer.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Do it as close to the source as possible, you are only one step away from doing it through a UI grid with this.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson what is a UI grid? Do you know of any MS sources on the performance of DPs?

Comment: @JohnnyGraber I added some code.

Comment: try using a profiler to see what lines are taking the most time to execute - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to profile, the question asks how efficient data-binding is, but the supplied code doesn't use data binding of any kind. It's more accurate to say that the most efficient way to achieve databinding is to have your logic / calculations running on a non-UI thread, and have your UI show contents of the View Model on the UI thread.

Comment: @EtherDragon it uses data binding in the background, i explained what is bound to what in the last sentence.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy are you aware of any free profilers?

Comment: @EtherDragon I see I haven't created any threads, so I am guessing everything is running on the UI thread. Is it faster if I put long calculations on a separate thread, even if the user is not interacting with the UI at the time of calculation?

Comment: @mihajlv i dont know any off hand but the one i posted has a free trail, i have used it in the past and found it very helpfull

Comment: Speedwise of EF framworks, the most I've seen is a claim that the latest version is faster. Faster doing what is the question, and possibly when and definitley how. If you could do all teh processing with a native stored procedure on a DBMS, it's likely to be much faster no matter what, is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long running task should never be run in the UI thread. If you run your long running calculation here your UI will be slow - independently of the speed of data binding. Since you block the updates of the UI.

If you change the value in a background thread then you have to use a dispatcher who makes a thread switch for you. This again comes with an overhead.

In both ways you have many factors who will slow down your application. 
And it doesn't really say anything reliable on the efficiency of data binding.

I suggest you write your code in a background thread and check if it is fast enough. If not use a profiler to check where your bottleneck is.

Answer (score 2):

> I do this in a for loop, and it is taking a really long time, the conditions is i=0; i<100000; 
>   i++). So I am wondering how efficient is data binding? And should it be used in scenarios like 
>   this?

That is the problem - false test. WHO CARES? If you think you can show 100000 updates on the screen with the user following you are already mistaken. Plus there is the problem of how / when the screen updates on a tight loop scenario - you may well be bound to 60 updates per second.

You do NOT test data binding to start with, you test ALSO 100.000 tostring calls.

Answer (score 1):

The right way here will be *to separate view from the model*. For this purpose use [**MVVM**](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications) (there are a lot of nice implementations of [**`INotifyPropertyChanged`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in web). When **`ViewModel`** will be prepared (I meen base ViewModel)- should implement something like:

*[ViewModel].cs* :

```
private double _c;
public double C
{
  get { return _c; }
  set 
  { 
      if (_c != value)
      {
          _c = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("C");
      }
}
```

*[Page]*.xaml

```
...
<UserControl.Resources>
  <vm:ViewModel />
  ...
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<TextBox x:Name="A" Text="{Binding C, Converter={StaticResource someConverter} Mode=TwoWay}" />
...
<TextBlock x:Name="B" Content="{Binding C, Mode=TwoWay}" />
...
```

After changing C from `ViewModel` or `View` it will automatically (with `INotifyPropertyChanged` help) update it in all bound places. This means that you should not run any loops or whatever you do before.

NOTE: From scratch I advise to use [MvvmLight](http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/).

Comment: Interesting Idea, I will look into the links. Thank you.